# Chrome Extension with Manifest V3 won't access WebRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to make a Chrome Extension, using Manifest Version 3, which accesses network requests originating from the webpage.

These are the relevant parts of the manifest, including permissions:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
          "css": ["styles.css"],
          "matches": [
            "<the site>"
          ],
          "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ],
}
```

Inside the content script, content.js, I registered a listener to `chrome.webRequest`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    (request) => {
        console.log(request);
    }
)
```

When I check the page console, other log lines from from content.js show up, but no web requests.

Furthermore, when I view the script inside the Chrome Developer Tools > Sources window, I see the following error.

[image: A call to chrome.webRequest that includes a JavaScript error indicating the property doesn't exist.]

Edit: This question was closed prematurely, because it is supposedly a duplicate. The related questions are based on V2 of the manifest, and this question is specifically about V3. The previous answers reference background scripts, which do not exist in V3.

Comment: Use service workers instead of content scripts.

Comment: You should also be aware of [Can Manifest V3 extensions use blocking Web Request?](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#when-use-blocking-webrequest)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have confused the `content.js` and `background.js`.
Try to put you code into `background.js`,the full code just like this:

```json
{
  "name": "My  Extension",
  "description": "This extension will run on your pages.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webNavigation","background"],
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/path/*"
      ],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "32": "images/icon32.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  }
}
```

and more,your `background.js` file should be like this:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    // do something here

  },
  {
    urls: [
      "https://yourhost.com/api/path",
    ],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest"],
  }
);
```

Comment: `"permissions": ["webRequest"]` this permission is not work with manifest version 3