# Chrome extension ignoring chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I simply want to console.log the url of any api requests to any web site. But I cannot get onBeforeRequest to trigger. I have tried a lot of combinations of permissions in the manifest. I have read a lot of docs and tried many other StackOverflow solutions. In particular this one verbatim: [Chrome Extension with Manifest V3 won't access WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258548/chrome-extension-with-manifest-v3-wont-access-webrequest)
I am using Chrome 120.0 on Windows, but have also tried Chromium 118.0 on Ubuntu. I've also tried examples I've found going back to manifest.json version 2. But I've never got anything to output in my console. Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "My  Extension",
"description": "This extension will run on your pages.",
"version": "1.1",
"manifest_version": 3,
"permissions": ["webRequest", "webNavigation","background"],
"host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
}
```

}

and here is background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    console.log("my url="+details.url);
  },
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
  }
);
```

If I load the unpacked extension to chrome, launch a new tab and run a search at google.com it seems like the "my url=" should be showing up in my inspect console. Yet I see nothing.

Comment: I've also tried the solution posted here because it seems very similar to my issue. But still  does not trigger the event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258548/chrome-extension-with-manifest-v3-wont-access-webrequest?noredirect=1&lq=1